ITaskScheduler::NewWorkItem fails with E_ACCESSDENIED
What permission should a user have to create a new work item in Task Scheduler? Also, how to check if any GPOs are restricting the creation of the work item in Task Scheduler.
Edit:

Tried adding tasks manually, was able to create tasks both under user and system account in the task schedular.
Also able to access the path C:\Windows\System32\Tasks using the system account. (Tried creating a directory and deleting a directory and was successful doing so)

(The API is executed under system account)

Do you have a particular reason to use the ITaskScheduler interface instead of the Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces?

Cannot reproduce using the classic sample. My Task was created in C:\Windows\Tasks. Also Please use the Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces instead.

I see the API can return E_ACCESSDENIED (if the caller does not have permission to perform the operation) but what permission an caller should have? Microsoft doc Does this have to do with IScheduledWorkItem interface, but the OS I'm working on is Windows 10.

You can refer to IScheduledWorkItem::SetAccountInformation for more information.
